# How to calculate a percentage on different values from same column with different criteria

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to write a query in SSRS (using SQL) to calculate an income statement percentage of sales for each month (the year is a parameter chosen by the user at runtime).  However, the table I have to use for the data lists all of the years, months, accounts, dollars, etc together and looks like this:

| ACCT_YEAR | ACCT_PERIOD | ACCOUNT_ID | CREDIT_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 4000 | 20000 |
| 2021 | 2 | 4000 | 25000 |
| 2021 | 1 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 2021 | 2 | 5000 | 7500 |
| 2021 | 1 | 6000 | 4000 |
| 2021 | 2 | 6000 | 8000 |

etc, etc  (ACCOUNT_ID =4000 happens to be the sales account)

As an example,
I need to calculate

```
CREDIT_AMOUNT when ACCT_YEAR = 2021, ACCT_PERIOD=1, and ACCOUNT_ID=5000
/
CREDIT_AMOUNT when ACCT_YEAR = 2021, ACCT_PERIOD=1, and ACCOUNT_ID=4000

* 100
```

I would then do that for each ACCT_PERIOD in the ACCT_YEAR.
Hope that makes sense...What I want would look like this:

| ACCT_YEAR | ACCT_PERIOD | ACCOUNT_ID | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 5000 | 0.25 |
| 2021 | 2 | 5000 | 0.30 |
| 2021 | 1 | 6000 | 0.20 |
| 2021 | 2 | 6000 | 0.32 |

I'm trying to create a graph that shows the percentage of sales of roughly 10 different accounts (I know their specific account_ID's and will filter by those ID's) and use the line chart  widget to show the trends by month.
I've tried CASE scenarios, OVER scenarios, and nested subqueries.  I feel like this should be simple but I'm being hardheaded and not seeing the obvious solution.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the percentages for period 2 be `30% (7500*100/25000)` and `32% (8000*100/25000)`?

Comment: I'm actually not concerned about the percentage format...SSRS formats percentages automatically with its built in controls.

Comment: I'm not asking about the formatting, I'm asking about the values. Where your example has `0.375` I calculate `0.3`, and where you have `0.4` I calculate `0.32`

Comment: Ah yes, math error on my end.  Late night...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important behaviour to note is that window functions are applied ***after*** the where clause.

Because you need the window functions to be applied ***before*** any where clause *(which would filter account 4000 out)*, they need to be used in one scope, and the where clause in another scope.

```
WITH
  perc AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    credit_amount * 100.0
    /
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN account_id = 4000 THEN credit_amount END
    )
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY acct_year, accr_period
    )
      AS credit_percentage
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  perc
WHERE
  account_id IN (5000,6000)
```

Comment: Bingo!  That works and it works very efficiently! I was not familiar with the "WITH" syntax...I will learn more about it now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just to use a matrix with a parent column group for ACCT_YEAR and a child column group for ACCT_PERIOD. Then you can use your calculation. If you format the textbox for percentage, you won't need to multiply it by 100.

Textbox value: `=IIF(ACCOUNT_ID=4000, Sum(CREDIT_AMOUNT), 0) = 0, 0, IIF(ACCOUNT_ID=5000, Sum(CREDIT_AMOUNT), 0) / IIF(ACCOUNT_ID=4000, Sum(CREDIT_AMOUNT), 0)`